# JVM Options List - still being maintained post Oracle?

Tags: jvm, jvm-arguments

Is the JVM Options List still being maintained anywhere? It seems to have disappeared from Oracle's website, but luckily the Wayback Machine has [a copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20110430195227/http://blogs.sun.com/watt/resource/jvm-options-list.html).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` to print available -XX options.
More diagnostic and experimental options can be added to list with following options:
`-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions` 
`-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions` (for Sun)
`-XX:+UnlockInternalVMOptions` (for JRockit)

*NOTE*: Current version of `javac` docs for Java 8 contains list of most `-XX` options: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Oracle's guide with 80+ options: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Pierre Laporte's service with full search for 907 options (supports JDK 8):
http://jvm-options.tech.xebia.fr/

Stas's guide with 800+ options: http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.com/2011/07/most-complete-list-of-xx-options-for.html

Collection of options for 1.6.0 and older versions of JVM: http://www.xenoc.demon.co.uk/A%20Collection%20of%20JVM%20Options.htm

Comment: Some more good links on similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486375/print-all-jvm-flags

Comment: Thanks a lot. This info is very well hidden I feel

Answer (score 5):

I used the same document very frequently as a reference, but unfortunately the original author was not maintaining it anymore.
I think it is still a valid list especially for older JVMs.

The www.xenoc.demon.co.uk referenced by Andriy is no more available...

So I'm trying to keep an updated version of the document here [A Collection of JVM Options](http://reins.altervista.org/java/A_Collection_of_JVM_Options_MP.html).