# JVM command line options

Tags: java, jvm-arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JVM Options List - still being maintained post Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833209/jvm-options-list-still-being-maintained-post-oracle)

Is there a page anywhere with a **definitive complete** list of the command line options available to run a JVM?  Everywhere I look I get referred to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html which is woefully incomplete. Even the [Oracle page on Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/index.html) just refers to the page above.

Apologies for such a basic question, but I keep coming across people suggesting useful looking options to tune the JVM that I can't find documented anywhere!  e.g. CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction

EDIT:
Following the link referenced by MicTech below, and then the links from that Q, it appears that: http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/most-complete-list-of-xx-options-for.html is the best reference so far.  Sigh.

Comment: Unfortunately JVM options are not all standard and supported in every implementation. I'm trying to keep an updated reference here: [A searchable collection of JVM options](http://reins.altervista.org/java/JVM_Options_search.php)

Answer (score 4):

There's an FAQ you might find useful about GC flags:

http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/faq.html

One thing to consider is those flags aren't "standard" so JVM implementations don't have to comply. This is why it's not listed in your link. They are implementation specific flags.

Comment: I realise they aren't standard across JVMs, they are however important if you are running a Sun/Oracle Hotspot JVM.  I can google the terms as well, but I was rather optimistically hoping there might be a detailed list somewhere.  It's mental that Oracle can't maintain even basic docs for such an important product.

Comment: I was pointing out that they are non-standard, therefore they are not in the standard specs. If you are using the Oracle Hotspot JVM, then this link *is* their documentation. Although I agree with you that something a tad more formal would be nice! :)

Comment: It's more than just being non-standard in terms of Oracle vs the World, they can vary between platforms as well. In the past, Windows, Linux, and Solaris have supported different non-standard switches, as have 32-bit vs 64-bit. OSX *currently* has different -X command line switches.

Comment: The content under that link does not exist anymore. Pro-Tip: use archive.org when posting valuable links here. But anyway i wonder: is there a complete list for every default JVM version out there?

Answer (score -4):

Oracle Hotspot specific options
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: That's the link I referred to in my question as being incomplete!