# What does the ":=" indicate in the JVM arguments list, in OpenJDK?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I wanted to see all the JVM arguments available in openjdk 1.8, and executed the following command:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version
```

It outputted all the available arguments in JVM, and I observed that a few flags are having the following format:

```
uintx MaxHeapSize   := 9449766912  {product} 

bool UseParallelGC  := true        {product}
```

In the above flags, what does the ":=" indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:=` denotes that the flag value was overriden either by JVM ergonomics or manually via a command line option.

[Here is](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/58d961f47dd4/src/share/vm/runtime/globals.cpp#l294) the source of the function that prints flags.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. Another think is there any java doc/article available explaining all the JVM arguments and categorized by GC algorithm type.

Comment: @PurushothamYanamala See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833209/jvm-options-list-still-being-maintained-post-oracle). The most complete list is in the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/58d961f47dd4/src/share/vm/runtime/globals.hpp#l499).

Comment: Plus a [separate file](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/58d961f47dd4/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/g1/g1_globals.hpp#l33) with G1-specific options.

Answer (score 0):

The := indicates it is the current value.

If you haven't changed it then this is the default value.

I often use this option with grep to find what I want.